# git push error "ssh: Could not resolve hostname git.assembla.com: .."

Tags: git, ssh

I did a git clone just fine, and my remote origin already exists.
However, every time I try to do a push or a pull I get the error message:

"ssh: Could not resolve hostname git.assembla.com: Name or service not known fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

At first, I thought there was a problem with my ssh keys, but the successful git clone shoots down that idea. Not sure what's wrong.
I'm completely new at git. Please help.

Comment: What does `git remote -v` say?

Comment: Could you post the commands you're using with appropriate substitutions for sensitive identifiers?

Comment: the remote server could have gone down after the clone. have you checked that?